# Deleting all but one record that are duplicates

Tags: mysql

I am trying to delete all records in a database with a duplicate and maintain one unique record.

The following is my query:

```
SELECT * FROM reg02_maininfo INNER JOIN(
  SELECT farmername,farmermobile,rowuuid FROM reg02_maininfo GROUP BY concat(farmername,farmermobile) HAVING COUNT(concat(farmername,farmermobile)) > 1 order by concat(farmername,farmermobile))
  temp ON reg02_maininfo.farmermobile = temp.farmermobile and reg02_maininfo.farmername = temp.farmername;
```

the following is my delete query

```
DELETE s FROM reg02_maininfo s INNER JOIN(
  SELECT farmername,farmermobile,rowuuid FROM reg02_maininfo GROUP BY concat(farmername,farmermobile) HAVING COUNT(concat(farmername,farmermobile)) > 1 order by concat(farmername,farmermobile))
  temp ON s.farmermobile = temp.farmermobile and s.farmername = temp.farmername;
```

How can i avoid deleting all the duplicate record and instead maintain a unique record

Comment: Note that it's often quicker to create a new table with just the rows to be retained.

Answer (score 0):

Did not check the syntax, because I am from mobile, but something like this would do the trick:

```
DELETE FROM reg02_maininfo WHERE rowuuid NOT IN (SELECT  
MIN(rowuuid) FROM reg02_maininfo GROUP BY 
concat(farmername,farmermobile))
```

So basically in the first step you select the min rowuuid for every group, and then delete the others, so that one will remain in each group.

Comment: It would be agonisingly slow, though :-(

Comment: Well, yes, but I assume he only needs it once. (And it would be strange to store millions of farmers with phone numbers :) )

Comment: rowuuid is not unique in the database and so can not be used as a unique identifier

Comment: Well, then just change to the unique key. Or if you don't have any, add an increment, and use that.

Answer (score 0):

For the concat(farmername,farmermobile) with duplicated  row you could try select the min  rowudid and check for not mathcing rowid

```
    DELETE s 
    FROM reg02_maininfo s 
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT concat(farmername,farmermobile)  name_mobile
        FROM reg02_maininfo 
        GROUP BY concat(farmername,farmermobile) 
        HAVING COUNT(concat(farmername,farmermobile)) > 1 
    ) t1 on t1.name_mobile = concat(s.farmername,s.farmermobile) 
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT min(rowuuid ) rowuuid
        FROM reg02_maininfo 
        GROUP BY concat(farmername,farmermobile) 
        HAVING COUNT(concat(farmername,farmermobile)) > 1 
    ) t pn t.rowuuid = s.rowuuid 
    where  t.rowuuid is null
```

or assuming  concat(s.farmername,s.farmermobile,s.rowuuid) is a valid pk

```
    DELETE s 
    FROM reg02_maininfo s 
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT concat(farmername,farmermobile,rowuuid)  my_pk
        FROM reg02_maininfo 
        GROUP BY concat(farmername,farmermobile) 
        HAVING COUNT(concat(farmername,farmermobile)) > 1 
    ) t1 on t1.my_pk = concat(s.farmername,s.farmermobile, rowuuid) 
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT min(concat(farmername,farmermobile,rowuuid) ) my_pk
        FROM reg02_maininfo 
        GROUP BY concat(farmername,farmermobile) 
        HAVING COUNT(concat(farmername,farmermobile)) > 1 
    ) t2 on t2.my_pk = (concat(s.farmername,s.farmermobile,s.rowuuid)
    where  t2.my_pk is null
```

Comment: my primary key is a composite farmermobile and rowuuid

Comment: @MirieriMogaka farmermobile is a component of a PK? That sounds nuts.